# filling the gap with grammar

Tags: grammar

I'd like to ask you some questions.

Firstly that is this.
" When one of a person's ten nearest neighbors bought a car, the [    ]that that person would buy a car of the same brand during the next week..."

I thought the word that is proper was possibilities though, the answer is chances.
Could you let me know why 'chances' is correct?

And there's another one.
"You add the team skills like [     ] you get from playing a sport."
I thought 'what' is proper though, the answer is those.
I wonder if what is also acceptable or not

Thank you!

Comment: Have a look at relevant prevalence for [the chance/chances of that happening.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+chance+of+that+happening%2Cthe+chances+of+that+happening&year_start=1910&year_end=2005&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20chance%20of%20that%20happening%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20chances%20of%20that%20happening%3B%2Cc0) Relatively speaking it's still an emerging expression, but  obviously both singular and plural are idiomatically fine. And it would be fatuous to argue for a *semantic* distinction.

Comment: 'The _likelihood_ that that person' ... sounds more idiomatic, to me.

Answer (score 1):

1. In this context, the word "chances" is equivalent to "probability" (see definition 1.1 here https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/chance). On the other hand, "possibilities" is more similar to "things that may happen." (see https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/possibility).
2. "Those" refers to specific things already mentioned (see https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/that), while "what" is a pronoun meaning "things that" (see https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/what). Accordingly, "those" is more specifically refers to team skills, while "what" could theoretically mean more than that.